# Cohomology to compute number of holes?

Tags: algebraic-topology, riemann-surfaces, homology-cohomology, complex-geometry

Can one use **cohomology** to compute the number of holes in a space $E$, where $E=R\times R$, $R$ is a Riemann surface of genus $g$, - i.e., is $\dim(H^n(E))$, and by Künneth's formula, $H^{n}(E) \cong \bigoplus_{k+l=n} H^k(R) \otimes H^l(R)$ in some way related to the number of $n$-dimensional holes in the space $E$? If yes, then how?

Comment: If $E$ would be a compact Riemann surface we have Riemann-Roch Theorem $$\dim H^0(E,\mathcal{O}_D)-\dim H^1(X,\mathcal{O}_D)=1-g+\deg D$$ Where $D$ is divisor on $E$. But this is only in $2$ dimensions, still it is a start.

Comment: @Kaladin True. What about other dimensions - more specifically, if $E=R\times R$, $R$ is a Riemann surface of genus $g$?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hirzebruch–Riemann–Roch_theorem

Comment: I've always thought this was more a heuristic than a precise statement-since what's an $n$-dimensional hole if not, I guess, the dual of an $n$-codimensional cohomology class? Anyway, if for instance $g=1$ then $E$ is a 4-torus, whose "holes" you might interpret by considering it as a quotient of a 4-dimensional hypercube.

Comment: What's an $n$-dimensional hole?

Comment: @DanielRust From Wikipedia: "The dimension of the $n$-th homology of $E$ turns out to be the number of "holes" in $E$ at dimension $n$."

Comment: Can we not then use Poincare duality?

Comment: @DanielRust That's true! I never thought about that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manifold $R$ is compact and orientable and so we can say the same for $E$, in which case we may use Poincaré duality to swap $r$th cohomology for $(4-r)$th homology.

So the number of $r$-dimensional holes in $E$ is $$\mbox{rank }\left(\bigoplus_{k+l=4-r} H^{k}(R)\otimes H^{l}(R)\right)=\sum_{k+l=4-r}\mbox{rank }H^k(R)\cdot\mbox{rank }H^l(R).$$

*(Hopefully I didn't mess up in the above - horrible indices)*

Comment: What if $4=r$? Then, $\mbox{rank }\left(\bigoplus_{k=-l} H^{k}(R)\otimes H^{l}(R)\right)=\sum_{k=-l}\mbox{rank }H^k(R)\cdot\mbox{rank }H^l(R),$ so what is $H^{-l}(R)$?

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar Then both $k$ and $l$ are equal to $0$ and so $\sum_{k=-l}\mbox{rank }H^k(R)\cdot\mbox{rank }H^l(R)=(\mbox{rank }H^0(R))^2$.